# Django rest auth with Google and VK?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I need SOCIAL **REST AUTH** in my Django project for  SPA, and iOS app.

The best library I know is  `django-rest-auth`  (for `allauth`), 
but there is no serialezers and views for rest auth with google and vk.
Does anybody has view and serializers for google and vk ? Or may be somebody know how to write it based on facebook serializer and view ?

Comment: I fix questoin. now it's moew specific. I need view and serializers  for rest auth with google and vk  using django-rest-auth library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one [Python Social Auth - Application - Django](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django)
here you have [documentation](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) you can find there google, VK and Instagram also.

Comment: I need REST AUTH!!! Just normal auth on site is pretty good in django-allauth and works fine. But there is strange problem with REST auth...